# is it possible to add custom property to StorageItemContentProperties of StorageFile in C#/XAML metro apps

Tags: c#, file, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, custom-attributes

I know I can retrieve the predefined properties of files via `RetrievePropertiesAsync()` method. But now I want to add one more my own custom property like description, is it possible ? I tried this code, but getting exception

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
    List<string> propertiesName = new List<string>();
    propertiesName.Add("CustomProperty");
    string a = "Come and knock on our door. We've been waiting for you. Where the kisses are hers and hers and his, three's company, too! Come and dance on our floor. Take a step that is new. We've a lovable space that needs your face, three's company, too! You'll see that life is a ball again and laughter is callin' for you. Down at our rendezvous, three's company, too! The year is 1987 and NASA launches the last of America's deep space probes. In a freak mishap, Ranger 3 and its pilot Captain William 'Buck' Rogers are blown out of their trajectory into an orbit which freezes his life support system and returns Buck Rogers to Earth five hundred years later.";
    IDictionary<string, object> extraProperties = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesName);
    extraProperties.Add((new KeyValuePair<string, object>("CustomProperty", a)));
    await file.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(extraProperties);
}

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in App2.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: The specified property name (CustomProperty) is invalid. The property may not be registered on the system.
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.
```

**P.S. : I want something like [this](http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-file.html)**

Answer (score 1):

The errors seem to indicate that the property needs to be defined in the property system to be retrieved. Quick MSDN search shows it could be done using the [PSRegisterPropertySchema function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it is only available to desktop apps.
[This topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes registering custom properties in more detail. Since there are already plenty of built-in properties and WinRT in Windows 8 as it is focuses on the fundamentals of it is unlikely that this would be possible from a Windows Store app. That means you could register the property with a desktop app, but your store app could not rely on its existence if it were to pass certification. The documentation for [StorageItemContentProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.aspx) mentions using QueryOptions to query for properties defined by other apps which is what you could try using if you want to search for properties defined by some other applications.

> **Note** Properties that are get or set using a property handler that is
>   defined by another app (like Microsoft Word) may not be accessible.
>   Instead, you can try to get these properties using a file query that
>   is backed by the system index. For more information, see
>   [QueryOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.queryoptions.aspx).

Comment: In short, it's not possible in metro apps, no ?
I have tried 'System.Comment' but it has 255 character limit.